# VertX HTTP GraphQL request responds with 'Query is missing'

Tags: graphql, vert.x, vertx-httpclient, vert.x-webclient

When attempting a HTTP request message to the Vert.X HTTP server endpoint, it fails with the error '**io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceThrowable: Query is missing**'.
This happens when the Query is passed as part of the request body. The same is NOT observed when the 'query' is provided in the URL.

Adding the following code did not help either.

`router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());`

Comment: Can you post the complete router setup (including `GraphQLHandler`) and explain how you send the request?